# show button if values are the same ionic2

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

When the page loads, i hide the submit button and i only want to display it when the value in textbox 2 matches with that of textbox 1

HTML

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>Reading</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="number" formControlName="readFirst"  [(ngModel)]="readFirst"></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>Retype Reading</ion-label>
  <ion-input  (ngModelChange)="checkValues($event)" type="number" formControlName="readSecond"  [(ngModel)]="readSecond"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<br>
<button *ngIf="showButton" ion-button block icon-left>
  <ion-icon name="send"></ion-icon>
  Submit Reading</button>
```

JS

```
  checkValues(){
    if(this.readSecond===this.readFirst){
      this.showButton = true;
    }else{
      this.showButton = false;
    }
  }
```

With my code the button disables even when the values do not match

Comment: are `readFirst` and `readSecond` formControls or data? Because you have used the same name for ngModel and formControlName

Comment: why are you using both template driven form as well as reactive forms? just use formControlName or ngModel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
checkValues(val: string){
  if(val === this.readFirst){
    this.showButton = true;
  }else{
    this.showButton = false;
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

I'd also display the button because it can be confusing when there is no button visible, so instead of `*ngIf` directive I would use `[disabled]="!showButton"`.

**Edit v2:**

Here you can check a simplified version of this on stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-9gwarw?embed=1&file=pages/home/home.html

Comment: with your script the button comes active when the page loads. But it show be disable when the page loads

Comment: Forgot to mention that you should set `this.showButton = false;` in the constructor or set it false by default when you declare it.

Comment: Updated my answer with a stackblitz example, check that pls.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide full code of HTML fill, But As your HTML Code, You do not need to have formControlName that gives :

> formControlName must be used with parentGroup directive

So I have to remove the formControlName and Here is Answer For you Question :

```
<ion-content padding>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Reading</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="readFirst"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Retype Reading</ion-label>
        <ion-input  (ngModelChange)="checkValues($event)" type="number"  [(ngModel)]="readSecond"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <br>
      <button *ngIf="showButton" ion-button block icon-left>
        <ion-icon name="send"></ion-icon>
        Submit Reading</button>
</ion-content>
```

Here is Ts File Code :

```
checkValues(event){
    console.log(typeof event) //Type of Value is String
    this.readSecond = event; 
    console.log(typeof this.readFirst); //Type of Value is String 

    if(this.readSecond===this.readFirst){
      this.showButton = true;
    }else{
      this.showButton = false;
    }
  }
```

If the **this.readFirst** and **this.readSecond** attributes defined as the type number, But **ngModel** won't give integer number. it gives a string.

Sometime you can see by consoling value of this.readSecond when you type the input box, this.readSecond gives **undefined** value. *because This happens when Angular tries to bind your model to the view before the model actually has a value.* Therfore that may causes to your function make wrong.

It is better to equal the this.readSecond variable to event that pass from **ngModelChange** method.

```
checkValues(event){
    this.readSecond = event;
}
```

**This is the view when first time you load the page :**

[image]

**This is the view after you enter a number in second field :**
If the both fields equal, Button will be shown up

[image]